# Issue parsing JSON response from an Ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

I've used an Ajax call to look up a single record from a database, the response comes back and JSON.parse doesn't work ("Unexpected identifier "object"") but I also get undefined when I try to access any of the values in it as an object.

Ajax call is:

```
 $.ajax({
                type        : 'POST', // define the type of HTTP verb we want to use (POST for our form)
                url         : 'php/mannoteslookup.php', // the url where we want to POST
                data        : formData, // our data object
                dataType    : 'json', // what type of data do we expect back from the server
                encode        : true,
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    JSON.parse(data);
                    var name = data.lastname;
                    console.log(name);
                    $('#notes-modal-title').append(name);
                },
                error: function(error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }
            })
```

The json is returned from this php snippet:

```
$sql = "SELECT lastname, journal, progress_notes FROM myrecords WHERE id=" . $id;
$result = $conn->query($sql); 
$dbdata = [];
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $dbdata[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($dbdata);
```

The following is what's returned:

```
[{"lastname":"Smalls","journal":"Nature Medicine","progress_notes":"2023-10-19 - Form notification received\r\n"}]
```

I'm still fairly new to this, but I've tried adding a header specifying json in the php, which seems to removes the quotes around the keys, but doesn't change anything. I must be missing something, would greatly appreciate any advice/assistance.

Comment: `JSON.parse(data);` returns the parsed data, and you ignore the returned value -though, I think you may be already getting an object anyway - don't know for sure, it's been 15 years since I used jquery

Comment: Is this a JS error or a PHP error? Also, be warned that your `SELECT` query is highly vulnerable for SQL injection. Have a look at prepared statements to avoid getting hacked

Answer (score 2):

[`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) is not required here because you specified `dataType : 'json'`. You're not actually using it anyway as you're not assigning the output from it. So `data` is already a JavaScript array, not a JSON string.

`data` is an array because of this code in your PHP, which puts all results (if any) into an array.

```php
$dbdata = [];
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $dbdata[] = $row;
}
```

If (as I suspect from your query) you only expect one result from the query, you could simply use

```php
$dbdata = $result->fetch_assoc();
```

Either way in your JS you need to check for a query which returns no results which you can do using [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) e.g.

```js
// array
name = data[0]?.lastname ?? 'Not found';
// result
name = data?.lastname ?? 'Not found';
```

Note that by using form data directly in your query (`$id`) you are vulnerable to SQL injection. I recommend reading [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) to see what that's about and how to make your code safe.

Answer (score 1):

Use as per below. data coming as Array having multiple objects

var name = data[0].lastname;

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick response, this helped!